# JavaScript Dynamic Updates Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I have a page which works fine on desktop but two elements give me problem on mobile browser.

These are a SVG Object and a Timer.

I have a 30 second timer which when completed animates the svg file.

This Timer works flawlessly in Desktop but when trying the same on mobile browser,

The timer dynamically updates only when I touch and scroll the screen up or down.

I tried using Remote Debugging with chrome using this guide: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

When I tried touching the screen in the debugger this error gets logged in the console.

`Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.`

The timer gets it's value from WebSocket, value is being sent via a server.js file.

Here is how I'm displaying the value in timer :

```
if(data.type == "countdown") {
  $(window).unbind("beforeunload");
  currentCountdown = (data.countdown-1);

  $("#countdown").text(currentCountdown.toFixed(2));

  clearInterval(cdInterval);
  clearInterval(barInterval);

  if(originalCountdown < (data.countdown-1)) {
    originalCountdown = (data.countdown-1);
  }
  cdInterval = setInterval(function() {
    currentCountdown -= 0.025;

    $("#countdown").text(currentCountdown.toFixed(2));

    if(currentCountdown <= 0) {
      clearInterval(cdInterval);
    }
  },25);
}
```

Comment: The error just means "We got a long running timer but the user wants to scroll. Screw the timer and postpone it so the user isn't stuck".

Long running timer callback means > 50 ms.

Comment: @KRONWALLED how can I resolve it?

Comment: I think there are not many ways to do that. You could split up your callback in smaller batches (< 50 ms preferably) so you don't block the mainthread for 30 seconds straight.

Comment: @KRONWALLED **Update** I just removed this Plugin I was using to keep the timer running even if user switches tab's and is not in that tab.

HackTimer by turuslan.
https://github.com/turuslan/HackTimer

When I remove this Js file, the issue is fixed. Any alternative way to do this? Or any other such plugins.